# Connect Gremlin shell to Titan Elasticsearch/Cassandra embedded instance?

Tags: titan

I'm using Titan 0.3.2 in embedded mode with Cassandra and Elasticsearch.  I am using the configuration documented in the [titan docs](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Example-Graph-Configuration#embedded-cassandra) for my `cassandra-es.properties` (fed into `titan.sh`/`titan.bat`):

```
storage.backend=embeddedcassandra
storage.cassandra-config-dir=config/cassandra.yaml

storage.index.search.backend=elasticsearch
storage.index.search.directory=/tmp/searchindex
storage.index.search.client-only=false
storage.index.search.local-mode=true
```

But I'm trying to get the right configuration for `bin/cassandra-es.local` to connect to the Titan server via the Gremlin client shell (with `g = TitanFactory.open("cassandra-es.local")` ).  If I try to use the default version included with the download:

```
storage.backend=cassandrathrift
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1
```

The graph won't know anything about the ES index ("`Index is unknown or not configured: search`").

If I configure it with:

```
storage.backend=cassandrathrift
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1

storage.index.search.backend=elasticsearch
storage.index.search.client-only=false
storage.index.search.directory=/tmp/cassandra/elasticsearch
```

It will create an ES instance on another port that seems to exist separately from the one used by the server.

My question: (how) can I set up my Gremlin console to properly communicate with the Titan Embedded Server?

Answer (score 0):

There was some recent discussion about this on the [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/aureliusgraphs/wP_wuVcAFCM/EqLMG7ArO0sJ).  It looks like it's actually not possible to run two ES instances on one machine, so one of the easier ways around this is to set up ES separately on a VM.

I tried out this solution, and it works fine with these lines in both `cassandra-es.local` and `titan-server-cassandra-es.properties`:

```
storage.index.search.backend=elasticsearch
storage.index.search.hostname=<VM ES server IP>
storage.index.search.client-only=true
```

I can now access the same ES index from both the Gremlin shell and the Titan server.