# Rexster query fails

Tags: titan, rexster

Running a query on titan-rexster-cassandra-0.4.1 :

```
http://localhost:8182/graphs/graph/tp/gremlin?script=g.V().has('place',WITHIN,Geoshape.circle(38.8951,-77.0367,50)).count()
```

fails with the following error:

```
{"message":"","error":"javax.script.ScriptException: com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: Could not process individual retrieval call ","api":{"description":"evaluate an ad-hoc Gremlin script for a graph.","parameters":{"rexster.returnKeys":"an array of element property keys to return (default is to return all element properties)","rexster.showTypes":"displays the properties of the elements with their native data type (default is false)","load":"a list of 'stored procedures' to execute prior to the 'script' (if 'script' is not specified then the last script in this argument will return the values","rexster.offset.end":"end index for a paged set of data to be returned","rexster.offset.start":"start index for a paged set of data to be returned","params":"a map of parameters to bind to the script engine","language":"the gremlin language flavor to use (default to groovy)","script":"the Gremlin script to be evaluated"}},"success":false}
```

Note: I am able to run it without any problems using gremlin console.

Thanks for any help

Comment: The error returned through Rexster is a bit trucnated to the client.  Is there anything in the Titan logs that show up (e.g a full stack trace?)

Comment: Hi Stephen. Here is the rexstitan.log [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b20ge9qhksm2ntr/rexstitan.log)

Comment: Not immediately seeing the problem...still looking at it.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it. I am not sure what the shard failure/ diskstorage failure is doing but I cant seem to get the query to run now that I have more than 100k vertices using rexster. I will try this on a different machine and update this post here.

Comment: Mmh, the only thing I can come up with is that Rexster might be configured to go against a different ES instance than the configuration file used in Gremlin? The exception indicates that the field has not be correctly initialized in ES but if it works in Gremlin I can only deduce that we are talking about two different ES instances???

Comment: Thanks for replying Matthias. What is the best way to check this? my titan-cassandra-es.properties uses: storage.index.search.backend=elasticsearch and I use GraphOfTheGodsFactory configurations which also uses elasticsearch. I start titan-server using '-c cassandra-es' and my gremlin uses ' = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties')'.

Comment: Update: I upgraded to 0.4.2 but to no avail. I havent tried it on a different machine yet.

Comment: I tried it on a different machine and the problem persists.

Comment: I see the problem. I was using gremlin console to do:1)  g = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties');2) GraphOfTheGodsFactory.load(g); and was expecting titan-all to have it available as : http://localhost:8182/graphs/graph/tp/gremlin?script=g.E.has('place',WITHIN,Geoshape.circle(37.97,23.72,50)). Should it not have worked? When i use rexster-console to load graphofthegods, it works fine. How can i insert 100k vertices using rexster in that case?

Comment: Many Thanks to Matthias and especially Stephen. It was indeed elastic search instance problem. These links were helpful: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014226/connect-gremlin-shell-to-titan-elasticsearch-cassandra-embedded-instance) and [link](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Using-Elastic-Search#elasticsearch-remote-configuration).